# How does slot attribute works in lightning-button?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-button, lightning-card, slots

I have the below example where a slot attribute is passed to the lightning-button to align with the lightning-card. Is there a documentation where I could read more about the slot property?

```
<template>
        <!-- Base variant: Makes a button look like a link -->
        <lightning-card title="Title">
                    <lightning-button label="Neutral" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-float_right" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-card>    
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots). I won't repeat all of it here, because that would be redundant, but here's the summary.

Slots are placeholders where a parent component can insert content directly into a child component. There are two types of slots, the default/unnamed slot, and named slots. In the child, you can specify where those slots are positioned:

```
<template>
 <slot>Default Header Content</slot>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td><slot name="left">Empty Left Content</slot></td>
     <td><slot name="right">Empty Right Content</slot></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</template>
```

Here, we define a default slot, and two named slots. Now, we can use them any way we desire:

```
<c-two-panel>
 <div>This will be the header content</div>
 <span slot="left">This will appear in the left hand panel</span>
</c-two-panel>
```

In this demo, the rendered content will appear as:

```
 <div>This will be the header content</div>     
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td><span>This will appear in the left hand panel</span></td>
     <td>Empty Right Content</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Notice how we didn't specify any content for `right`, so it defaulted to the content provided in the child template.

One final note, default slots can appear in multiple places; if so, the content that was passed in will appear in each place.

I have included all of this in a [WebComponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/m6HXOpmutu1dH5loGmKN/src/app.html) demo for you to fork and play around with.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox but my question was more towards using slot in lightning-button. It seems like there is a slot action that can be used for lightning-card. I just found the documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/documentation

Comment: @Krishnamurthy In your code sample, `slot="actions"` tells the `lightning-card` where to place the `lightning-button`. The attribute is not "actually" a property of lightning-button, it is a special attribute used to determine the button's location in the card.

Comment: Yes understood. Thank you so much for the clear explanation!

Comment: @Krishnamurthy You're welcome. Glad I was able to help.